# Java 2D game -- simple but efficient way to load maps?

Tags: java, dictionary, 2d, loading

I'm having problems on deciding what way to load preset maps for a simple game I'm testing, and I'd like to get it out of the way (make it clear) before I tackle future projects.

I've reviewed code from many tutorials and sources, but the code they use when loading images and implementing maps they designed either seemed too complicated or too simple(which just seems to be inefficient)

examples are: 1.) (and probably the most inefficient)
--> coding individual id on a 2D array

```
int[][] map =
{
    {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
};
```

2.) Saving the map file on notepad, and is stored as ASCII characters or just the common characters.

3.) Saving the map on an image file(i.e. a png file from paint) by using colours to determine the tile. The colours in the image pixels are then translated into RGB values which is then read by the computer and then converted into a tile.

I'd just like to know whether I'm over thinking it and these are good practices to code. If not, where can I find good online resources or source code(I don't have the luxury for books)

Efficiency wise, load times, storage and all other things shouln't matter very much since its a very simple program (simple jumps, character movement, no mobs, no points) -- though id like to consider that textures will be part of the game in the future.

edit: I'd like to add that I've finished, though not furnished simple 2d platformers using all 3 methods before at some point in time. It's just maybe theres a better way of doing things that aren't too advanced.

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.  You might get a better reception at [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Store it as a byte array and load it direct from a stream.

Comment: Stop worrying about things that "seem" inefficient. Try something out and stop worrying about premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how large you maps are.

For small stuff, hardcoding is just fine, it finds its natural limits in the limits imposed by the class file format (max. size of initializer code).

Any of the other methods you describe just use a more or less simple to read format and (abuse) a third party program (notepad, paint etc) as the "editor". Efficiency wise they aren't escpecially good or bad, consider that the overhead of using an ASCII file is relatively small (one byte per tile, in the worst case you only have 2 tiles, 7 bits wasted) or in case of PNG you even get *free* compression from the PNG format.

Go with what fits your project best - if its complicated (many tiles, possibly multiple layers) and maps are large consider making your own editor (you should already have all the code for rendering in your game, just add a basic UI for editing...) to simplify editing. Store in any format you find practical, be it raw byte arrays or serialized objects. It won't matter in any normal sized project a single person can pull off.

Answer (score 0):

When I deal with game maps I create maps.txt and store it in a ArrayList

I don't draw the titles each time I run the game. I create the background image once map01.png

That way you only need to draw the player in your fps.

I use the ArrayList to check if the players location + 1 in the moving direction is equal to 0, if so it can walk on it. I use other numbers to if I want water, moving high grass or entering doors etc.

Hope that helps.